# shell script to delete a directory whose name is digit number?

Tags: shell, unix

In Unix, how can I write a shell script to delete a directory whose name is digit number ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution removes directories that is a number or more

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -fr +([0-9]) # use when directories are non-empty
rmdir +([0-9]) # use when you know the directories are all empty
```

Comment: what is mean 'shopt -s extglob ' ?

Comment: it means extended globbing. It enables you to use `+,?`, etc. see the bash man page for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shell expansion for that:

```
$ mkdir 1 2 3 4 5
$ rmdir [0-9]
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If the digit is 0 just: `rmdir 0`

Answer (score -1):

Delete all folders just containing digits in the current directory:

```
for i in `find . -maxdepth 1 | grep "^./[0-9]\+\$"`; do rm -rf $i; done
```

Comment: `find` can handle regular expressions using the parameter `-name`: `find /current/dir -name "[0-9]"`. Take care when using `rm -rf`, you might delete something that you didn't wanted to delete.